# sqlite3_column_count always return 1

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
selectSql = "SELECT title FROM list";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, selectSql, -1, &statement, NULL);
countColumn = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

NSLog(@"%d",countColumn);
```

why does this count always return 1
In fact,table has 18 records

Comment: @sunajledif NSLog(@" what?! ");

Comment: @notreallyJake NSLog(@"%d",countColumn);  ? , he is NSLogging the columnCount , there was a question mark in my first comment, I guess you didnt notice it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one because your statement only `select`s **one** column (`title`).  Try this and see what it returns:

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
selectSql = "SELECT * FROM list";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, selectSql, -1, &statement, NULL);
countColumn = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

NSLog(@"%d",countColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean row, not column, count?
Column count (in your case title) is indeed always 1.