# sqlite: sqlite3_column_count always returns 0

Tags: ios, sqlite, cocoapods, google-analytics-api

I am using sqlite in an iOS project. However sqlite3_column_count is always returning 0, even though I'm certain the query does return some columns (I don't even think a SELECT query in SQL is possible with zero output columns). The strange thing is this behaviour changes depending on the version of the library I link against, and specifically what compile time options were used for that library.

These are the compile time options used for the version of the library which doesn't work:

```
COMPILER=clang-8.0.0 (clang-800.2.34)
ENABLE_API_ARMOR
ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
ENABLE_JSON1
ENABLE_LOCKING_STYLE=1
ENABLE_RTREE
ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT
HAS_CODEC
HAVE_ISNAN
MAX_MMAP_SIZE=20971520
OMIT_AUTORESET
OMIT_BUILTIN_TEST
OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION
SYSTEM_MALLOC
THREADSAFE=2
```

Here are the flags for the version which does work:

```
COMPILER=clang-8.0.0
SYSTEM_MALLOC
THREADSAFE=1
```

What could be causing this behaviour?

UPDATE 2016/12/01

Here is a project which can be used to recreate the issue: https://github.com/iannewson/Stackoverflow40895740.git

ViewController.swift contains this code:

```
Test.doDbStuff()
```

This function contains the following:

```
public static func doDbStuff() {
    do {

        var db :OpaquePointer?
        let dbPath = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("\(Date.init().timeIntervalSince1970)".replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "") + ".db")
            .path

        var returnCode :Int32 = sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db)
        if SQLITE_OK != returnCode {
            preconditionFailure("Failed to open db")
        }

        var stmt :OpaquePointer?
        returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "CREATE TABLE Things (name TEXT)", -1, &stmt, nil)
        if SQLITE_OK != returnCode {
            preconditionFailure("Failed to prepare table creation SQL")
        }
        returnCode = sqlite3_step(stmt)
        if SQLITE_DONE != returnCode {
            preconditionFailure("Failed to execute tbl creation SQL")
        }
        returnCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type ='table'", -1, &stmt, nil)
        if SQLITE_OK != returnCode {
            preconditionFailure("Failed to prepare count SQL")
        }
        returnCode = sqlite3_step(stmt)
        if SQLITE_ROW != returnCode {
            preconditionFailure("Failed to execute count SQL")
        } else {
            let columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(stmt)
            print("columnCount: \(columnCount)")
            let name = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0))
            //print("Num tables: \(count)")
            print("Table name: \(name)")
        }

    } catch let error {
        preconditionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This function works fine in all cases, and always creates the table and retrieves its name from sqlite_master without error.

ViewController.swift also contains this code:

```
    Database.instance().executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Things (name TEXT)")
    Database.instance().printTableNames()
    Database.instance().withStatementFromSql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type ='table'", callback: {statement in
        while SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(statement) {
            print("Column index: \(sqlite3_column_count(statement))")
            let name = SqlHelper.toString(statement, columnName: "name")
            print("Table: \(name)")
        }
    })
```

This code creates a table, and then attempts to retrieve its name from sqlite_master. This works fine with the project set up as it is currently in the repo, so to reproduce the error you need to install the Google Analytics pod. You can do this by uncommenting `pod 'Google/Analytics'` in Podfile and running `pod install`. Now when you attempt to run this project, the first set of code (`Test.doDbStuff()`) will still work fine, but the second set of code, which uses `Database`, will either error with EXC_BAD_ACCESS or return `SQLITE_MISUSE` from `sqlite3_step`.

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: @CL I've added example code and a link to a the most concise SCCE I could make.

Comment: Probably a bug in `withStatementFromSql`.

Comment: @CL. That method has been in production for years without issue. The problem only emerges when this code is used with the Google Analytics CocoaPod, which I think uses its own version of sqlite, which is why I thought the compilation flags were relevant.

Comment: if you use another sqlite library (or browser) does it return a non-zero column_count?

Comment: @I-V I'm unaware of another SQLite library for iOS. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to have that db on another machine? Such as an OSX

Comment: Try changing the select from "select name..." to "select *" see this similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682005/sqlite3-column-count-always-return-1; one more thing: make sure you aren't clobbering &stmt